# How do I remove these bounding box outlines?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, interface, visibility

At some point these popped up and I’ve been unable to disable them. They are tied to the models as newly created objects don’t have them (see the sphere next to them).

I’ve looked for a physics visualization option as that was the problem for most similar problems I could find, but I found nothing and from what I've found I don’t think it’s a setting anymore, or just in a different mode or something.

[image: Example]

I’ve searched pretty much the entire properties window, though it’s possible that I’ve somehow missed it after five passes of everything.

I’ve noticed turning off the overlays turns the boxes off, but if I turn off the individual options and leave the overlays overall on, it’s still visible. It’s also visible regardless of what object is selected and the current mode (object, edit, sculpt, etc.).

I’m on Blender 2.93.1.

[Blend File](https://ufile.io/m97c278i)

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Object Properties -> Viewport Display -> Bounds?

Comment: Okay pasteall doesn't work cause it'll only accept 24 MB (which seems incredibly small for blend files) but here it is through Ufile. https://ufile.io/m97c278i
And unfortunately that isn't the problem Jan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the *object data properties* for each object, un-check "Texture Space" for the viewport display:

[image: Visibility]

Comment: Thank you so much!